# Spring Rest Web Application - Threads are Blocking

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jprofiler, thread-dump

We have a Spring MVC Based web application which exposes REST Services (XML I/O). But when we hit with 50 Users (through JMeter), all of our threads go into blocked state. We captured Thread Dump through JProfiler. So we have 49 Blocked threads and others are in Waiting state.

So here is dump of two threads. Thread 3 is Blocked.

```
Thread "default task-3":
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.find(java.lang.String) (line: 143)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.find(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (line: 59)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[ ]) (line: 41)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.reflect.Method) (line: 77)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl) (line: 317)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Transducer, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor) (line: 195)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeNonElementRef) (line: 137)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 47)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor94.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ])
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo) (line: 88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeTypeInfo) (line: 467)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 72)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 22)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor96.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ])
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo) (line: 88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeTypeInfo) (line: 467)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 63)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor95.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ])
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo) (line: 88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeTypeInfo) (line: 467)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 72)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeElementPropertyInfo) (line: 22)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor96.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ])
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[ ]) (line: 423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimePropertyInfo) (line: 88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl, com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeClassInfo) (line: 448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.runtime.RuntimeTypeInfo) (line: 467)
```

Thread 30 is in Waiting State.

```
Thread "default task-30":
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) (line: 175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await() (line: 2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take() (line: 442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask() (line: 1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (line: 1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (line: 624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run() (line: 748)
```

Some more info about Blocked Thread.

```
default task-51 - priority:5 - threadId:0x00007fbe64127000 - nativeId:0x227f - state:BLOCKED
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:121)
- waiting to lock <0x000000008c22d560> (a com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector.inject(Injector.java:48)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:51)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:77)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$GetterSetterReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:317)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:45)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor94.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:72)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:22)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor96.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:88)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:135)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:448)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:467)
```

I am not sure what exactly the problem is?

Comment: how is your JAXB stuff setup? Have you directly bean'd the Java classes or have you setup an registered spring `jaxb2marshaller`?

Comment: Threads in waiting state are thread pool threads which are idle and waiting for new tasks. Can you add source code of rest method which blocks your threads?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe We do not have any registered spring jaxb2marshaller. We bean'd Java classes directly by @ XmlRootElement annotation.

Comment: Can you share full thread dump?

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski Comment section doesnt allow me to paste full thread dump.